# SVG Pattern and Gradient together

Tags: css, html, svg, graphics, web-frontend

Is there a way to apply both pattern and gradients to an element together using filter or any method in SVG?

I do not want to create a duplicate element(any shape) to achieve this. Its a maintenance overhead.

The below image is a sample of my expected output.

[image: A way to achieve pattern and gradients to an element together in SVG]

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100%'>
<defs>
    <pattern id='tile' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' width='75' height='75' viewBox='0 0 50 50'>
        <line x1='1' y1='0' x2='51' y2='50' stroke='#19203d' stroke-width='2'/>
        <line x1='49' y1='0' x2='-1' y2='50' stroke='#19203d' stroke-width='2'/>
        <line x1='50' y1='0' x2='0' y2='50' stroke='#313763' stroke-width='2'/>
        <line x1='0' y1='0' x2='50' y2='50' stroke='#313763' stroke-width='2'/>
    </pattern>
    <radialGradient id='l' cx='50%' cy='200%' fy='0' r='201%'>
        <stop offset='0%' style='stop-color:#fff; stop-opacity:.1;' />
        <stop offset='10%' style='stop-color:#000; stop-opacity:0.1;' />
        <stop offset='30%' style='stop-color:#000; stop-opacity:0.3;' />
        <stop offset='90%' style='stop-color:#000; stop-opacity:0.55;' />
        <stop offset='100%' style='stop-color:#000; stop-opacity:.6' />
    </radialGradient>
</defs>
<rect fill='#39466b' width='100%' height='100%'/>
<rect fill='url(#tile)' width='100%' height='100%'/>
<rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='url(#l)'/></svg>
```

> I DON'T WANT TO DUPLICATE THE ELEMENT FOR FILLING GRADIENT AND PATTERN. THE ABOVE CODE HAS DUPLICATION OF THE ELEMENT.

Comment: and what have your tried yet.

Comment: Create a pattern, stick a shape with a gradient in it. Where exactly are you stuck. Adding some markup to show what you've done so far would help us to help you.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I have added the code above to explain what I am looking for.

Actually I am developing chart framework, I want to apply both pattern and gradients to the bar chart without duplicating the rect element. Is there any way?

Comment: I suspect you could do this with an fePointLight or feSpotLight source applied to the element via a filter as this can be combined with a pattern. i.e. ignore the gradient.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson. I understand what you mean. But my chart configuration contains gradient overlay and pattern overlay. So I cannot use the spotlight or pointlight for it.

I think the only way is to duplicate the element and group and translate together. Right?

Comment: I think you've painted yourself into a corner with your requirements.

Comment: I understand Robert. Now I'm compromised to have one element for pattern and other for gradient. Thank you for ur inputs. It really helped.

Answer (score 7):

Whilst this still does duplicate elements, it does so in the defs tag meaning you can apply it one visible element.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100%'>
<defs>
<pattern id='tile' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' width='75' height='75' viewBox='0 0 50 50'>
    <line x1='1' y1='0' x2='51' y2='50' stroke='#19203d' stroke-width='2'/>
    <line x1='49' y1='0' x2='-1' y2='50' stroke='#19203d' stroke-width='2'/>
    <line x1='50' y1='0' x2='0' y2='50' stroke='#313763' stroke-width='2'/>
    <line x1='0' y1='0' x2='50' y2='50' stroke='#313763' stroke-width='2'/>
</pattern>
<radialGradient id='l' cx='50%' cy='200%' fy='0' r='201%'>
    <stop offset='0%' style='stop-color:#fff; stop-opacity:.1;' />
    <stop offset='10%' style='stop-color:#000; stop-opacity:0.1;' />
    <stop offset='30%' style='stop-color:#000; stop-opacity:0.3;' />
    <stop offset='90%' style='stop-color:#000; stop-opacity:0.55;' />
    <stop offset='100%' style='stop-color:#000; stop-opacity:.6' />
</radialGradient>
<rect id="bgRect" fill='#39466b' width='100%' height='100%'/>
<rect id="gradientRect" fill='url(#l)' width='100%' height='100%'/>
<rect id='tileRect' fill="url(#tile)" width='100%' height='100%'/>
  
<filter id="test" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" y="0">
<feImage xlink:href="#bgRect" result="bg" />
<feImage xlink:href="#tileRect" result="tile" />
<feImage xlink:href="#gradientRect" result="waves" />
<feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in="bg" />
    <feMergeNode in="tile" />
    <feMergeNode in="waves" />
  </feMerge>
  </filter>
  
  </defs>

<rect filter='url(#test)' width='100%' height='100%'/>  
</svg>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/chrisgannon/pen/acfb7fd4f64a7ceb612167929286b33c

It uses rects as the source for feImage but unfortunately this is not supported in FireFox and IE support is patchy.

It's by no means a perfect solution but it might illustrate a way forward.