# How to apply Gradient in SVG Element on which a Pattern is already applied

Tags: html, svg, linear-gradients

I have some SVG elements on which there are some pattern already applied. The pattern is applied as fill color. That means the pattern fills up whole SVG element. Basically i want to partially fill up my element using the pattern.

From different sources, i found that i can apply **linear gradient** to partially fill an element.

So my question is can i use gradient on a pattern or there is any way to partially fill an element by **pattern**?

**NOTE** A same element can be drawn(with gradient) on top of the original element(with pattern) to achieve this. But drawing a same object on top of it is not going to help me.

**What I have tried**

```
<defs>
<pattern id="patternToApply" width="9px" height="9px" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 10 10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <rect id="rectPatternToApply" width="25" height="25" x="0" y="0" stroke-width="0" fill="Firebrick"></rect>
  <image id="imgPatternToApply" width="10px" height="10px" x="0" y="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/aspx/charting/images/nonie/hash.gif"></image>
</pattern>

<linearGradient id="gradientToApply" x1="0" x2="0" y1="100%" y2="50%">
    <stop offset="30%" stop-color="url(#patternToApply)"/>
    <stop offset="70%" stop-color="white"/>
</linearGradient>
```

From Robert Longson's Comment i tried following:

**First**

```
<defs>
<pattern id="pathCrownGradient" width="9px" height="9px" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 10 10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <rect id="rectPatternToApply" width="25" height="25" x="0" y="0" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#gradientToApply)"></rect>
  <image id="imgPatternToApply" width="10px" height="10px" x="0" y="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/aspx/charting/images/nonie/hash.gif"></image>
</pattern>

<linearGradient id="gradientToApply" x1="0" x2="0" y1="100%" y2="50%">
    <stop offset="30%" stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset="70%" stop-color="white"/>
</linearGradient>
```

**Second**

```
<defs>
<pattern id="pathCrownGradient" width="9px" height="9px" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 10 10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" fill="url(#gradientToApply)">
  <rect id="rectPatternToApply" width="25" height="25" x="0" y="0" stroke-width="0" fill="red"></rect>
  <image id="imgPatternToApply" width="10px" height="10px" x="0" y="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/aspx/charting/images/nonie/hash.gif"></image>
</pattern>

<linearGradient id="gradientToApply" x1="0" x2="0" y1="100%" y2="50%">
    <stop offset="30%" stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset="70%" stop-color="white"/>
</linearGradient>
```

**Third**

```
<defs>
<pattern id="pathCrownGradient" width="9px" height="9px" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 10 10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" fill="url(#gradientToApply)">
  <rect id="rectPatternToApply" width="25" height="25" x="0" y="0" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#gradientToApply)"></rect>
  <image id="imgPatternToApply" width="10px" height="10px" x="0" y="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/aspx/charting/images/nonie/hash.gif"></image>
</pattern>

<linearGradient id="gradientToApply" x1="0" x2="0" y1="100%" y2="50%">
    <stop offset="30%" stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset="70%" stop-color="white"/>
</linearGradient>
```

Unfortunately still not working.

Comment: You could apply a gradient to the elements that make up the pattern.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson for commenting, actually i was following your comment from this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411381/svg-pattern-and-gradient-together).

Actually i have tried to do that, but it was not working. I am updating my question what i have tried. Will you please let me know where i am making the mistake.

Comment: @RobertLongson: I have added what i have tried, but still couldn't make it work. What Is the right way to reference a gradient?

Comment: The elements in the pattern must reference the gradient, not the pattern itself.

Comment: I think you are referring to following way:

`<pattern id="pathCrownGradient" width="9px" height="9px" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 10 10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect id="rect" width="25" height="25" x="0" y="0" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#gradientToApply)"></rect>
      <image id="img" width="10px" height="10px" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="hash.gif"></image>
    </pattern>
  
    <linearGradient id="gradientToApply" x1="0" x2="0" y1="100%" y2="50%">
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="red"/>
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="white"/>
    </linearGradient>`

But sill not working

Comment: I've no real idea what you want this to look like so I can't suggest anything else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102626/discussion-between-anan-xon-and-robert-longson).

Comment: @RobertLongson: Actually i want to fill an element half portion by a pattern, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into account the order in which you define what your final display will be.

So first create a pattern.

Then use that pattern to create another pattern.
If that is to your liking, you can then use path and use the second pattern as a fill.