# How do I mix pattern and gradient into one path?

Tags: svg

It is important for the customer that I mix both the gradient and the pattern to be applied to the same path ...is it possible ?

The scheme is as follows:

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad" x1="7%" y1="0%" x2="93%" y2="100%" >
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,29,139);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <pattern id="bg" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" viewBox ='0 0 80 80' patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle fill="0x0" cx="3" cy="3" r="2.5"></circle>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
  <g fill="url(#grad)">
    <path id="path3" d="M0,0 1000,0 1000,1000 0,1000z"  fill="url(#bg)"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I would like to get a gradient + pattern = (fill path)  https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/eYNgRyP  as in the sandbox, **but only apply gradient and pattern to the same path**

Comment: You can apply a linearGradient as a fill to a shape within a pattern, and then apply the pattern as a fill to the path.

Comment: @MichaelMullany show me how - I've been doing magic for four hours

Comment: @MichaelMullany I put the real svg in the snippet

Comment: What is something that has a gradient and a pattern supposed to look like? Do you just want to apply the gradient as a fill on the pattern's circle?

Comment: this should work https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/eYNgRyP  but with one path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411381/svg-pattern-and-gradient-together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to create a new `<pattern>` that combines both the gradient and the original pattern.

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad" x1="7%" y1="0%" x2="93%" y2="100%" >
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,29,139);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <pattern id="bg" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" viewBox ='0 0 80 80' patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle fill="0x0" cx="3" cy="3" r="2.5"></circle>
        </pattern>

        <pattern id="both" width="100%" height="100%">
           <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"/>
           <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#bg)"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
  <g>
    <path id="path3" d="M0,0 1000,0 1000,1000 0,1000z"  fill="url(#both)"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

As  Michael Mullany said, apply the gradient to the elements within the pattern. Apply the pattern to the element `path`

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad" x1="7%" y1="0%" x2="93%" y2="100%" >
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,29,139);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <pattern id="bg" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" viewBox ='0 0 80 80' patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle  fill="url(#grad)" cx="3" cy="3" r="2.5"></circle>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
  <g >
    <path id="path3" fill="url(#bg)" d="M0,0 1000,0 1000,1000 0,1000z"  ></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Maybe so?

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad" x1="7%" y1="0%" x2="93%" y2="100%" >
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,29,139);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <pattern id="bg"  x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" viewBox ='0 0 80 80' patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       
            <circle fill="black"  cx="3" cy="3" r="2.5"></circle>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
  <g >
     <rect width="1000" height="1000" fill="url(#grad)"/>
 <path id="path3" fill="url(#bg)" d="M0,0 1000,0 1000,1000 0,1000z"  ></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: there is no linear gradient

Comment: there is no linear gradient - I need to mix them before they fall into the same path

Comment: If you added rect, you don't need to do this

Comment: if you watched the sandbox I added another path myself

Comment: @RobertLongson I completed the question

Answer (score 3):

If you want a gradient applied to the entire path vs. a shape within the pattern then, you either have to use a second path or use a filter. Here is a version with a filter (doesn't work on Firefox - you have to inline the svg fragment in order to get cross-browser - but this should give you the idea.)

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1000" y2="1000" >
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgb(255,29,139)"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgb(255,255,255)" />
        </linearGradient>
      
        <pattern id="bg" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" viewBox ='0 0 80 80' patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle fill="0x0" cx="3" cy="3" r="2.5"></circle>
        </pattern>
      
      <rect id="bgGrad" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"/>
      
      <filter id="insertBGGrad">
        <feImage xlink:href="#bgGrad"/>
        <feComposite operator="over" in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </filter>

    </defs>
    <path id="path3" d="M0,0 1000,0 1000,1000 0,1000z" fill="url(#bg)" filter="url(#insertBGGrad)"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Works on Chrome/Win 10. Where is it not working for you?

Comment: But Paul's is a better solution. Avoid filters if you can do it another way.

Comment: Yes - I said in the answer that it wouldn't work in Firefox because Firefox doesn't support fragment identifiers as an input to feImage. To get cross browser you have to inline the fragment as a data-URI. That's more work so I didn't do it.